# How can one combine some rows of a table and show them as columns in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

```
record   element   value
1      | 8767    | Name1
1      | 8768    | City1
2      | 8767    | Name2
2      | 8768    | City2
```

And then I want to create report like this

```
A       | B
Name1   | City1 
Name2   | City2
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: And how do you connect name1 to city1 if you have nothing that defines which goes with which

Comment: you should try in `PIVOT` Table..

Comment: If `element` value is always even for cities and odd for names, you can join two tables that you get by `element % 2 = 1` and `element % 2 = 0`

Comment: What you're using is EAV model. You can PIVOT the data you have so it looks like regular column approach design. You probably won't be able to use indexes while working with the view you get after pivoting. What you should google to get answers is "mysql pivot table" "eav model".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    a1.value AS A,
    a2.value AS B 
FROM a AS a1 join a AS a2 ON
    a1.record=a2.record
WHERE a1.element=8767 AND a2.element=8768;
```

If you want to test it, you can setup using

```
USE test;
CREATE TABLE a (record int not null, element int not null, value text not null);
INSERT INTO a VALUES (1, 8767, 'Name1'), (1, 8768, 'City1'), (2, 8767, 'Name2'), (2, 8767, 'City2');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join this table to itself. In this case you will use its name twice in your query, thus you need to give them some query-unique name. The end-requlst will be as follows:

```
SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM TABLE A
LEFT JOIN TABLE B ON A.RECORD=B.RECORD AND A.ELEMENT=B.ELEMENT
WHERE A.VALUE LIKE 'Name1%' AND B.VALUE LIKE 'City%';
```

Good luck!

Comment: I would guess that `NameN` and `CityN`  are just placeholders, for real names and cities.

Comment: I think you must not join on RECORD. It seems that record=8767 stands for a name and the other for a city.

Comment: @Micha Yes, it seems really so.